# Core Data, huge file, slow

Tags: core-data, filesize

I am writing an application, which stores a huge number of very short strings (mostly one to three unicode chars) and lots of relationships. This results in a massive overhead for storing the relationships in the XML format and even more so in the Binary format (which is strange). So if I use XML or Binary, i get huge files and very long save and load times.

The SQLite format is more compact and saves faster (especially in case of small changes), but for some reason the queries using predicates with format "$something BEGINSWITH[c] fieldInMyObject" do not work, and i can't do without them.

Is there anything i can do to reduce the volume of the files and speed up loading and saving (apart from using SQLite directly)?

Best regards, 
Timofey.

**UPD**
Here is the code for saving the data:

`‐ (IBAction) saveAction:(id)sender {`

```
NSError *error = nil;

if (![[self managedObjectContext] commitEditing]) {
    NSLog(@"%@:%s unable to commit editing before saving", [self class], _cmd);
}

if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
}
```

}

And here is the code for loading data (both for creating new files and loading existing ones):

`- (void) panelReturnedURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel];
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSBinaryStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil 
                                                            URL:url 
                                                        options:nil 
                                                          error:&error]) {
        [NSApp presentError:error];
    }
    managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [mainWinController window];
}`

And i don't don't save when objects are modified, the context is saved when the application quits or when the user explicitly saves it.

Comment: XML is not famous for its speed, thus if you don't need human readable data, runtime changes, portability, etc. you should focus on binary files. What technique(s) do you use to save/load data? Sequential or random access? What do you do when the data are modified? Try to elaborate more and preferably provide some code.

Comment: Well, i just used the "saveAction:" method that was generated by Xcode... I didn't think there were any other methods (i am a bit of a noob). I'll try and look into any other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

XML and binary can be slow for large files because they have to be read entirely into memory in one chunk in order to work. If you have a lot of data your really need to use an SQLite store.

Your problems with the predicate having nothing to do with the SQLite store. That type of predicate is used routinely. I would suggest posting a seperate question with a layout of your entities and the predicate you want to use: